# how to change the img.src value in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a code in JavaScript where it creates an HTML page, just a div and an image tag. The tricky part for me is I'm trying to generate/populate this image tag with `img.src` value with the help of an if statement.

The code goes something like this.

```js
var propertyname;
var content = document.createElement('div');
var img = document.createElement('img');
if (propertyname == 'house') {
  img.src = 'house.jpg';
}
content.appendChild(img);
```

How can I make this code better. Right now the image is not being inserted when I check in the developer tools for Chrome the `img.src` is `undefined`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: yes above code `propertyname` is not mention.is `!= house`

Comment: well, the `propertyname` isn't `"house"` what do you expect it to do?

Comment: propertyname  name is null so src not set

Comment: your code worked fine if `propertyname == house`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
var propertyname;
var url= 'url';
var content = document.createElement('div');
var $img = $('<img id='img12'>');
if (propertyname == 'house') {
  $img.attr('src', url).css({ 'height': height, 'width': width });
           
}
content.appendChild($img);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var propertyname = "house";
var content = document.createElement('div');
var img = document.createElement('img');
if (propertyname == 'house') {
   img.src = 'house.jpg';
}
content.appendChild(img);

document.getElementById("demo").appendChild(content);
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

It's working fine when your `propertyname` variable has a value.

```js
var propertyname = 'house';

var content = document.createElement('div');
var img = document.createElement('img');

if (propertyname == 'house') {
  img.src = 'https://placehold.it/300x100';
}

content.appendChild(img);
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(content);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this. This is working:-

```js
var propertyname='house';
var content = document.createElement('div');
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src="http://i1.wp.com/sourabhsomani.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/cropped-10407476_754773647911718_359758615924605603_n-1.jpg?fit=240%2C240"
if (propertyname == 'house') {
  img.src = 'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/718784555281309696/KRYC9gLU_400x400.jpg';
}
content.appendChild(img);
document.getElementById("myDiv").appendChild(content);
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try like this

```
 var x = document.createElement("IMG");
 x.setAttribute("src",'house.jpg');
```

Answer (score 2):

*Given code is working fine for me if `propertyname == "house"`*

Check below example:-

```js
var propertyname = "house";
var content = document.createElement('div');
var img = document.createElement('img');
if (propertyname == 'house') {
  img.src = 'https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/bb/ce/4f/bbce4fcc3d8560b612e766704aba4dd2--tudor-cottage-tudor-house.jpg';
}
content.appendChild(img);

document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(content);
```

Answer (score 1):

See: [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)

Try

```js
var propertyname;
var content = document.createElement('div');
var img = document.createElement('img');
if (propertyname == 'house') {
  img.setAttribute('src', 'house.jpg');
}
content.appendChild(img);
```